# How to pass data to an ng-bootstrap popover

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm writing an Angular app with Bootstrap, using ng-bootstrap. I have a popover encapsulated in a component like this:

HTML (popover component)

```
<div>
  <div>Data 1: <i>{{ v.data1 }}</i></div>
  <div>Data 2: <i>{{ v.data2 }}</i></div>
</div>
```

This popover is opened in another component:

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let v of vector">
    <span [ngbPopover]="popOver" popoverTitle="Pop title">Open</span>
</div>

<ng-template #popOver>
    <popover></popover>
</ng-template>
```

I need to pass the v parameter of the ngFor to the popover. How can I achieve this?

Comment: just add @Input to your popover component

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: You didn't provide the component code. And it's basic angular technique https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: The component code is just the html above.

Comment: No you provided the template not the component code.

Comment: Because I didn´t add anything to the TS file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a fundamental technique of angular [how to pass data to component](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding).

So you need to update your popover component:

popover.component.html

```
<div>
  <div>Data 1: <i>{{ data.data1 }}</i></div>
  <div>Data 2: <i>{{ data.data2 }}</i></div>
</div>
```

popover.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'popover',
  templateUrl: './popover.component.html'
})
export class PopoverComponent {
  @Input() data: any;
}
```

Then update your ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let v of vector">
  <span [ngbPopover]="popOver" popoverTitle="Pop title">Open</span>
  <ng-template #popOver>
    <popover [data]="v"></popover>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-laqjog